# Recursive method with ArrayList

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I'm having some troubles with an excersise from my programming class.

I had a class like this:

**UML of the class**

[image]

And I have to make a public method that return the total quantity of sub sectors from an sector.

**This is the code for the entire class:**

```
public class Sector {

private int number;
private String name;
private String type;

private ArrayList<Sector> sectors = new ArrayList<>();   

public Sector(int number, String name, String type) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}
```

**and the recursive method is this**

```
public ArrayList<Sector> getTotalSectors(Sector sector, ArrayList<Sector> sectors) {                    
    sectors.add(this);            
        if (sector.getSectors() != null) {
            for(Sector sector1 : sector.getSectors()) {
                getTotalSectors(sector1, sectors);
            }
        }        
    return sectors;
}
```

But i can't make it work, i get this when i try to call the method in the main

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
```

** Main class **

```
Sector s1 = new Sector(100, "sales", "sales");
    Sector s1_1 = new Sector (101, "minor sales", "minor");
    Sector s1_2 = new Sector (102, "mayor sales", "mayor");
    Sector s1_2_1 = new Sector (102, "lala sales", "lalala");

    s1.getSectors().add(s1_1);
    s1.getSectors().add(s1_2);
    s1_2.getSectors().add(s1_2_1);

s1.getTotalSectors(s1, s1.getSectors());
```

Any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't follow what you're trying to do.  But you can't be simultaneously iterating through a collection with a for-each loop and modifying it with the add method.  Perhaps you need to redesign this.

Comment: you are iterating over an arrayList and at the same time modifying it, cant do that. Instead of `for` loop, use iterator

Comment: for every new `Sector` you are going to have a new `arrayList` - I do not think this is what you want to do.

Comment: "public method that return the total quantity of sub sectors" do you want to get the count or create a new ArrayList<Sector> variable with all the sub Sectors on it.

Comment: it has to return an ArrayList with all the sub sectors of one sector, but at the same time one sub sector can have more sub sectors

Comment: for example:
sector1
sector1_1
sector1_2
sector1_2_1

if i use the method for sector 1, it should return an arraylist with 3 objects (sector1_1, sector1_2, sector1_2_1)

Comment: Where's the code that initially calls `getTotalSectors()`?

Comment: the     getTotalSectors()     it's called on the main class

Comment: I wasn't looking for an address, I'm asking you to post it.

Comment: Don't post your code in the comments, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39008692/edit) your post.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your getTotalSectors method, replace your for loop within the if-structure with the code below. The exception you are getting should not happen if you use the Iterator class.

```
   Iterator<Sector> iter = sectors.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Sector sector1=iter.next();
    getTotalSectors(sector1, sectors);
   }
```

Comment: I'm getting an StackOverflowError with this

Comment: Could you show the code for the getTotalSectors method?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23066029/ sorry i can't post it in a "easy to read" format on the comments, new on stackoverflow

Comment: Why do you have to call the getTotalSectors method within the while statement if you are not assigning the value to a variable?

Comment: Of course you're getting a `StackOverflowError`.  The first time you call `getTotalSectors`, you're passing `s1` and the list inside `s1`.  The first thing that method does is to add `s1` to its own list.  Then, as you work through the `for` loop, one call that you'll make to `getTotalSectors` will have those same two arguments.  That's what makes your `StackOverflowError`.  Therefore, the way you've designed `getTotalSectors`, it's invalid to pass a `Sector` and the list inside the same `Sector`.  If you need to do that, then you'll need to redesign the method.